# How to generate .net core or .net standard csproj file?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a program that generates C# projects as output.
Previously I was generating .Net Framework projects using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build/

However, now I need to generate .Net Standard projects instead and I cannot figure out a good way to do that. Microsoft.Build seems to only generate .Net Framework projects and I cannot find any other library that would do the job.

What is a good way to generate a .Net Core or .Net Standard project?

Comment: dotnet core projects actually have very simple structure so I ended up  just creating them using text templates

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new.) specifically using the option `--framework netstandard<version>` or `--framework net6.0` specified in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates)